# Loop through Model items dynamically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

How to navigate between items but show only 3 of them dynamically at a time.

This is my code that don't do match but shows the concept

```
<div class="col-1 text-center" style="border: 1px dotted orange;">
    next
</div>

@foreach (var post in Model.Take(3))
{
    <div class="col-3" style="border: 1px dotted orange;">
        <h3 style="overflow: hidden;">@post.Title</h3>
        <h6 style="overflow: hidden;">@post.BodyText</h6>
    </div>
}
<div class="col-1 text-center" style="border: 1px dotted orange;">
    back
</div>
```

The desired functionality:

previous - **post1** - post2 - post3 - next

***click next 5 times***

previous - post4 - **post5** - post6 - next

if its even possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correct but it seems like you would like to implement some sort of paging.
There is also a class `PagedList<T>`which might help (downloadable from NuGet `Install-Package PagedList.Mvc`).

Down below you find a tutorial which includes a step by step example also covering paging.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application